Python - The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process when someone else runs the code
I wrote a small script in spyder for my colleagues and I to use to update a simple excel file. When I run the code I get no errors, but when my colleague runs the same code we get the error that the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
I've tried closing my program while they run theirs, saving the documents with new names and running again, and nothing has changed the error.
Here's how the files look in my program. I've removed the beginning of the directory string here as it contains company information.
#Files 
swx_f = Internal Team Library\\Team\\CS\\Darian\\CARISCSPSWX_Report\\SWX' + dayval + '.xlsx'

caris_f = Internal Team Library\\Team\\CS\\Darian\\CARISCSPSWX_Report\\CARIS' + dayval + '.xlsx'

cspcaris_f = Internal Team Library\\Team\\CS\\Darian\\CARISCSPSWX_Report\\CSPvsCARIS' + dayval + '.xlsx'

Error code:
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\\\\Users\\\\saed\\OneDrive\\Internal Team Library\\Team\\CS\\Darian\\CARISCSPSWX_Report\\SWX202408.xlsx' -> 'C:\\Users\\\\saed\\\\Internal Team Library\\Team\\CS\\Darian\\CARISCSPSWX_Report\\File Archive\\SWX202408.xlsx'
 
 
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
 
Traceback (most recent call last):
 
  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec

    exec(code, globals, locals)
 
  File c:\users\saed\.spyder-py3\monthly closure.py:107

    shutil.move(swx_f, dest_new)
 
  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\shutil.py:868 in move

    os.unlink(src)
 
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\\\\Users\\\\saed\\ \\Internal Team Library\\Team\\CS\\Darian\\CARISCSPSWX_Report\\SWX202408.xlsx'

Code:
 ###Headers
length = 0
header1 = ['AWB Number']
header2 = ['Departure Date', 'Match Status', 'Flight Number', 'Net Revenue Prorated', 'Source']
swxhead = ['AWB Number', 'Origin', 'Destination', 'SWX Net Amount']

###Lists/Dicts
swx_list = []

caris_dict = {}
cspcaris_dict = {}
final_dict = {}

###Record Counts
swxcount = 0
cariscount = 0
cspcariscount = 0
#combinedcount = 0

###Build SWX List

workbook1 = xl.load_workbook(filename=swx_f)
wb1 = workbook1.active

for line in wb1.iter_rows(values_only=True):
    if line[2] is not None:
        if '724-' in line[2]:
            swxamt = float(line[10])
            amtround = np.around(swxamt, decimals=2)
            swx_list.append([line[2].strip(), line[4].strip(), line[5].strip(), amtround])
            swxcount +=1
        else:
            pass
    else:
        pass
workbook1.close()
shutil.move(swx_f, dest_new)        
        
###Build CARIS List      

workbook2 = xl.load_workbook(filename=caris_f)
wb2 = workbook2.active

for row in wb2.iter_rows(values_only=True):
    if row[3] is not None:
        if '724-' in row[3].strip():
            awb = row[3].strip()
            depdate = row[4]
            flt = row[5]
            netrev = row[6]
            
            if awb in caris_dict.keys():
                caris_dict[awb] += [depdate, flt, netrev, 'CARIS']
                cariscount +=1
            else:
               caris_dict[awb] = [depdate, flt, netrev, 'CARIS'] 
               cariscount +=1
        else:
            pass
    else:
        pass
     
workbook2.close()
shutil.move(caris_f, dest_new)        
            

###Build CSP vs CARIS List

workbook3 = xl.load_workbook(filename=cspcaris_f)
wb3 = workbook3.active

for r in wb3.iter_rows(values_only=True):
    if r[1] is not None:
        if '724' in str(r[1]):
            awb2 = str(r[1])
            depdate2 = r[4].strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
            flt2 = r[3]
            netrev2 = r[6]
            
            if awb2 in cspcaris_dict.keys():
                cspcaris_dict[awb2] += [depdate2, flt2, netrev2, 'CSPCARIS']
                cspcariscount +=1
            else:
                cspcaris_dict[awb2] = [depdate2, flt2, netrev2, 'CSPCARIS']
                cspcariscount +=1

        else:
            pass
    else:
        pass
workbook3.close()
shutil.move(cspcaris_f, dest_new)        


###Build Combined CARIS and CSP vs CARIS Dict

for k in caris_dict.keys():
    if k in cspcaris_dict.keys():
        final_dict[k] = ['Matched'] + caris_dict[k] + cspcaris_dict[k]
        cspcaris_dict[k] += ['Matched']
    else:
        final_dict[k] = ['No Match'] + caris_dict[k]
for j in cspcaris_dict.keys():
    if cspcaris_dict[j][-1] == 'Matched':
        pass
    elif j in caris_dict.keys():
        final_dict[j] = ['Matched'] + caris_dict[j] + cspcaris_dict[j]
    else:
        final_dict[j] = ['No Match'] + cspcaris_dict[j]
        
for l in final_dict.keys():
    if len(final_dict[l]) > length:
        length = len(final_dict[l])
    else:
        pass
            
###Write Final File###

###Create report counts for error checking 
indtotal = swxcount + cariscount + cspcariscount

####Headers

multiplier = int(length / 5)
variablehead = header2 * multiplier
final_head = header1 + variablehead

###Create workbook and name sheets 
wb = xl.Workbook()
ws1 = wb.create_sheet('CARIS CSP', 0)
ws2 = wb.create_sheet('SWX', 1)
ws3 = wb.create_sheet('Record Counts', 2)

ws3.append(['Record Counts - Individual Reports', 'SWX Records:', swxcount, 'CARIS Records:', cariscount, 'CSP vs CARIS Records:', cspcariscount, 'Total:', indtotal])
#ws2.append(['Record Counts - This Report', '', '', 'Combined Records:', combinedcount, 'Unique Records:', uniquecount, 'Total:', reporttotal])

ws2.append(swxhead)
for t in swx_list:
    ws2.append(t)
    
ws1.append(final_head)
for w in final_dict.keys():
    newlist = [w] + final_dict[w]
    ws1.append(newlist)

    
outputfile = r'C:\\Users\\' + user_code + '\\\\Internal Team Library\\Team\\CS\\Darian\\CARISCSPSWX_Report\\Completed Reports\\SWXCARISCSP Records Report ' + dayval + 'TESTTEST.xlsx'
wb.save(outputfile)        
wb.close()

messagebox.showinfo("Success!", "Report Completed")

master_with_quotes = '"' + outputfile + '"'
os.system('start "EXCEL.exe" {}'.format(master_with_quotes))


do multiple people work on the same excel file simultaniously? ist it opened?

Can u share the python script?

Please also share the exact error code u are receiving from the  script. Probably try to catch the exception and print it to debug more

The file is not opened while we update it and only the two of us can access it. My program and excel are both closed while my colleague tries to run the code

You could try installing psutil which you could use to determine which process(es) have the file open
